# GC overhead limit exceeded - Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, garbage-collection

i get this error after waiting long time for my code to execute and its pointing me to this method

```
public Iterable<Board> neighbors() {
        Queue<Board> q = new LinkedList<>();
        int n = dimension();
        int x = 0, y = 0;
        outer:
        // do some stuff to get the x and y
        if (y+1 < n) {
            the line where i get the error -> int [][]arr = new int[n][n];
            for (int i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++) {
                arr[i] = Arrays.copyOf(tiles[i], n);
            }
            // do some stuff
            Board br = new Board(arr);
            if(!this.equals(br)) {
                q.add(new Board(arr));
            }
        }
       if (y-1 >= 0) {
           int [][]arr = new int[n][n];
           for (int i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++) {
                arr[i] = Arrays.copyOf(tiles[i], n);
            }
            // do some stuff
            Board br = new Board(arr);
            if(!this.equals(br)) {
                q.add(new Board(arr));
            }
        }
       if (x-1 >= 0) {
           int [][]arr = new int[n][n];
           for (int i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++) {
                arr[i] = Arrays.copyOf(tiles[i], n);
            }
            // do some stuff
            Board br = new Board(arr);
            if(!this.equals(br)) {
                q.add(new Board(arr));
            }
        }
        if (x+1 < n) {
            int [][]arr = new int[n][n];
            for (int i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++) {
                 arr[i] = Arrays.copyOf(tiles[i], n);
             }
            // do some stuff
            Board br = new Board(arr);
            if(!this.equals(br)) {
                q.add(new Board(arr));
            }
        }
        return q;
    }
```

i basically need to copy tiles array and make changes to the copy "arr" but keep the tiles array without changing to use it later..i really don't like the way i'm doing it *copying and pasting code* i think its inefficient but no other way comes to my mind so i would like to know why i get this error "i know its because GC taking more time and not doing alot" but i want to know why its happening in this case also if there is better way to copy the array.
also **i increased the heap memory to -Xmx1600m**

Thanks for your time.

Comment: How large is `n` in this case?

Comment: You could safe some GC work by initializing `arr` with `new int[n][]` instead of `new int[n][n]`.

Comment: @Compass n is 3

Comment: @Socowi tried..its still taking time so it will give same error probably

Comment: i don't think style has anything to do with it but tried anyway @Socowi

Comment: Is `tiles` also a 3×3 array? I executed your code and had no problems. And when I increase `n` to 1000000, I get `Java heap space` instead of `GC overhead limit exceeded`. Do you call your method (or another method) extremely often?

Comment: yeah tiles is 3x3..i think my method gets executed many times and i suspect its going into infinite loop cause it really takes long time to give me the error..could it be because of infinite loop?..also n never increases its always 3

Comment: It is likely that the problem arises from creating a lot of objects in a *short period* of time. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1393503/6770384). Maybe (no guarantees) the problem goes aways if you fix the loop. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @ٍٍsocowi i'm trying to write program that solves the 8 puzzle in least amount of steps using A* algorithm

Answer (score 1):

## The Problem

It is likely that the problem arises from creating a lot of objects in a *short period* of time. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393486/error-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded/1393503#1393503) for more information.

At the moment, one `Board` consist of at least four objects:

- The Board itself
- The array `arr` inside the board
- The three arrays inside `arr`

## Creating Less Objects

Our goal is to create fewer objects (arrays). Since you want to deal with small boards only, we could use one `long` to store the complete 3×3 board. A `long` has 64 bit. We use 64 / 9 = 7 bits per field to store the value on that field:

```
state = ... 0000100 0000011 0000010 0000001 0000000
           4th field   ↑   2nd field   ↑   0th field
                   3rd field       1st field
```

The following class handles the bit operations.

```
class Board {

    private final static int SIDE_LENGTH = 3;
    private final static int FIELDS = SIDE_LENGTH * SIDE_LENGTH;
    private final static int BITS_PER_FIELD = 64 / FIELDS;
    private final static long FIELD_MASK = (1 << BITS_PER_FIELD) - 1;

    private long state;

    public Board() {
        for (int field = 0; field < FIELDS; ++field) {
            set(field, field);
        }
    }

    /** Copy constructor. */
    public Board(Board other) {
        this.state = other.state;
    }

    public int get(int x, int y) {
        return get(coordinatesToField(x, y));
    }

    public void set(int x, int y, int value) {
        set(coordinatesToField(x, y), value);
    }

    private int coordinatesToField(int x, int y) {
        return SIDE_LENGTH * y + x;
    }

    private int get(int field) {
        return (int) ((state >>> (field * BITS_PER_FIELD)) & FIELD_MASK);
    }

    private void set(int field, int value) {
        int shift = field * BITS_PER_FIELD;
        state &= ~(FIELD_MASK << shift);
        state |= (long) value << shift;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int field = 0; field < FIELDS; ++field) {
            sb.append(get(field));
            sb.append((field + 1) % SIDE_LENGTH == 0 ? "\n" : "\t");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    // TODO implement equals and hashCode
}
```

When using this class, you don't have to deal with arrays anymore, which saves not only a lot of objects, but also the copy code in your prorgram.

The class also works for 1×1, 2×2, and 4×4 boards, but not for larger ones due to the 64 bit limit.

## Usage Examples

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create and print the initial board
    // 0 1 2
    // 3 4 5
    // 6 7 8
    Board b = new Board();
    System.out.println(b);

    // Copy an existing board
    Bord copy = new Board(b);

    // Set the upper right field to value 8
    copy.set(2, 0, 8);

    // Print the center field
    // 4
    Syste.out.println(copy.get(1, 1));

}
```

## Additional Ideas

You even could avoid creating `Board` objects at all, and just store the `long` values. But that doesn't help when you are using generics (such as `LinkedList`) because of Java's auto boxing.

Also note that `LinkedList` wraps each entry in an additional node object. Maybe you can use a more efficient DataStructure like a circular buffer.

Depending on what you are doing, you might as well have a look at the [Flyweight design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern).